# Asp.Net Trying to get ClientID

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, clientid

I'm a bit stuck trying to figure out how to pass a controls ClientID to one of my JavaScript methods.

Edit:  I'm realizing I should mention this is an Asp.Net App built on .Net 3.5.  Can't use .Net 4.0 tricks but the 4.0 tricks you guys mentioned below in the replies are definately something to keep in mind and would solve this readily.

When I do something like what follows, I end up having my Javascript method getting the literal text of <%= gvCompanySelector.ClientID %> showing in my argument.

Below is what my Asp.Net control looks like in the Aspx page.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="aShowList" runat="server" 
onclick="javacript:showCompanySelector('divCompanySelector','<%= gvCompanySelector.ClientID %>');" 
CssClass="button">Select</asp:HyperLink>
```

my javascript method looks like this.

```
function showCompanySelector(divName,gridName) {
            var elem = document.getElementById(divName);
            var gridElem = document.getElementById(gridName);
            if (elem.style.visibility === 'visible') {
                elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                elem.style.height = '0px';
                gridElem.style.height = '0px';
            }
            else {
                elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
                elem.style.height = '200px';
                gridElem.style.height = null;
            }
        }
```

It's my gridName argument that's getting a value of <%= gvCompanySelector.ClientID %> passed into it.  When I'm expecting the argument to show something like the ct100_blahlbah_gvCompanySelector ClientID.

What kills me is that if I use just a standard Anchor tag, , the ClientID passes just fine.

And if the suggestion is to use an AddHandler or build the javascript call in my Code Behind, I'd like to avoid it.  I'm trying to have some sense of consistency in this code. =-/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I found was to create a global variable.  Probably like this less than using AddHandler type coding but at least it keeps my javascript WITH my javascript.

```
<script>
var gvCompanySelectorClientID = = '<%= gvCompanySelector.ClientID %>';

function showCompanySelector(divName,gridName) {
            var elem = document.getElementById(divName);
            var gridElem = document.getElementById(gridName);
            if (elem.style.visibility === 'visible') {
                elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                elem.style.height = '0px';
                gridElem.style.height = '0px';
            }
            else {
                elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
                elem.style.height = '200px';
                gridElem.style.height = null;
            }
        }

</script>

<asp:HyperLink ID="aShowList" runat="server" onclick="javacript:showCompanySelector('divCompanySelector','<%= gvCompanySelectorClientID %>');" CssClass="button">Select</asp:HyperLink>
```

Would love any other recommendations.

Comment: Note this is "my" ideal answer when using .Net 3.5 (or less than .Net 4.0).  Thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to pass Client Id from your argument. You can do like this also.

```
function showCompanySelector(divName) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(divName);
        var gridElem = document.getElementById('<%= gvCompanySelector.ClientID %>');
        if (elem.style.visibility === 'visible') {
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            elem.style.height = '0px';
            gridElem.style.height = '0px';
        }
        else {
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
            elem.style.height = '200px';
            gridElem.style.height = null;
        }
    }
```

Another way of doing is for asp.net 4.0 Static client Id mode. You can override cilent mode as static and then you can pass 'gvCompanySelector' in your control it self.http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2009/07/client-id-of-control-in-aspnet-40.html

If you are using lower version of .NET Framework you can override client id like this - http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Feb/24/Overriding-ClientID-and-UniqueID-on-ASPNET-controls

First create a class library called 'MyControls'. Add Referecen to System.web and then override grid view like below.

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace MyControls{
public class MyGrid : GridView
{
    public override string ClientID
    {
        get
        {
            return ID;
        }
    }
}}
```

Then on aspx side register your control like below.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyControls" Namespace="MyControls" TagPrefix="myc" %>
```

Then use control like below.

```
 <myc:Mygrid Id="myGrid" runat="server">

 </myc:Mygrid>
```

If you want to see more information about overriding control see following link-https://web.archive.org/web/20210323170551/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012308-1.aspx

Comment: because I'm using this method in multiple places and don't want 5 methods doing the exact same thing simply because I can't pass a clientid properly.

Comment: If you are using asp.net 4.0 higher version then you can make your client id mode static and the directly pass 'gvCompanySelector' in your argument. Because server tag in server control definition will not work. See more information of client id-http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2009/07/client-id-of-control-in-aspnet-40.html

Comment: drool...  I want it.  But can't have it.  I'm assuming...  Can't use .Net 4.0.  Company isn't putting it on web servers yet.  Just trying to stay waaaaaaaay ahead (backwards day) of the times.

Comment: You can also override your client id - just like below- http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Feb/24/Overriding-ClientID-and-UniqueID-on-ASPNET-controls to have staic client id in other framework

Comment: I'm using .Net 3.5.  And the override option assumes I built this as a control versus page functionality.  Ideally I would love to build this as a full control, but in the real world, project completion date != length of time to perform this task.  Very usefull info though.  thank you!

Comment: Its very easy to override it. Will no take more then 5 minutes

Comment: I have added code in my answer. Please go through it.

Comment: I'd rather not have to customize a GridView.  I can see how that would work, just not exactly what I'm going for.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('the id of the required control');
            var gridElem = document.getElementById('the id of the required control');
```

no need to pass it to javascript,and change the `clientIDmode` of the control to `static`

**Or**

no need of passing it in the parameters

```
var gridElem = document.getElementById('<%= idofthecontrol.ClientID %>');
```

some times it may show the error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

then use

```
 var gridElem = document.getElementById('<%# idofthecontrol.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: I'm using the javascript method in a few places. This Javascript method specifically supports key functionality i'm building. Specificaly something like a multicolumn dropdown box.

Comment: wait... I just caught... "Change ClientIDmode to static".  Can I do this per element/asp.net control?  er...  more specifically can I make just my hyperlink control have a static ID?  And I assume that changing the ClientID mode to static means the ID I give to the element doesn't get goofed up as some stupid ct100_blahblah_Im_helping_the_developer_id type of id...

Comment: Tease.  ClientIDMode is a .Net 4.0 thang.  Thanks though!  Neat trick I'll definately keep in mind!

Comment: @RobK.:accept my answer and do upvote if it has helped you,and you are welcome